# Clearing something after adding it do an ArrayList clears the ArrayList too

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an ArrayList containing Arraylists, this is the code:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> results = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
ArrayList<String> row = new ArrayList<String>();
```

What I want is that the `results` ArrayList contains the `row` ArrayList. I thought that after adding something to an ArrayList, it would be hardcoded into that ArrayList. But it appears that the contents of the ArrayList are still related to the contents of the variable that I add to it, because when I run this code:

```
row.add("ROW 1 ITEM 1");
row.add("ROW 1 ITEM 2");
row.add("ROW 1 ITEM 3");
row.add("ROW 1 ITEM 4");
row.add("ROW 1 ITEM 5");
row.add("ROW 1 ITEM 6");
results.add(row);
row.clear();
log(results.toString());
```

The result that is logged in the console is [[]]. Is there any way I can use it this way?

Comment: I don't get it, if you clear the row ArrayList then it is empty. What do you expect?

Comment: @andgalf I think he was asking why the `results` ArrayList is empty after deleting `row` ArrayList.

Comment: @pro_cheats the results ArrayList is not empty. It contains an empty lists.

Comment: Precisely!! @andgalf

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, Java works with references. If you call `clear` on a reference that refers to an `ArrayList`, then other references referring to the exact same memory will see the same. That the `ArrayList` is empty.

If you want to keep your content, then save it to a different `ArrayList` instance.

Answer (score 3):

This happens because Java works with references and not clones / copies by complex datatypes (non-complex types are `int`, `char` and similar).

In your case this means the `ArrayList<String> row` gets some position in memory and is stored there.
If you now add `row` straight to `result` via `result.add(row);` you just adding a reference (or pointer in C++) to the original position of `row` in memory to `ArrayList result`.

So this means if you change anything in `row` it will be also changed in `result` because both objects refer to the same spot in memory with is modified.

To solve this problem, you have to create a new copy each time you want to add `row` a copy of it which refers to a different spot in memory and then add the copy to result.
1. Way:
create a method like this:

```
ArrayList<String> createCopy (ArrayList<String> orginal) {
  ArrayList<String> copy = new ArrayList<String>()
  for (String s:orginal) {
    copy.add(s);
  }
  return copy;
}
```

2. Way:
Look up you favorite way how to create deep clones/copies of ojbects in java and use that.

Answer (score 1):

You are adding reference of ArrayList row  to results. Once row.clear() is called all the elements will be removed. You can log before clearing or instead of adding reference create new ArrayList and deep copy the list.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is not working because you are removing the row ArrayList before the print. Unless you copy the contents to the results ArrayList, that data is being removed because I believe the row ArrayList is being referenced when you call that .toString() method

Answer (score 0):

That’s because the contents in an array list aré object’a references, so you have two references pointing to row, one is the variable row, and the other references is the first element of the array results, if you change the object using the row reference (variable), it will affect the arraylist inside the arraylist result

Answer (score 0):

You can understand this in terms of how the memory is allocated to objects in Java.

Initially you have only one **`row`** Arraylist and you are adding that ArrayList to **`results`** Arraylist.

You need to understand that, you have **instantiated/alloted memory to** only one ArrayList that is **`row`**, and **`results`** ArrayList contains that **`row`** object only, **NOT** any new object.

Hence, when you delete the **`row`** that object is deleted.

As there is only one object in the memory, your output is empty after deletion.